# Backgrid client side filtering is pulling data from previous as well as current data set

Tags: jquery, filter, pagination, backbone.js-collections, backgrid

Backgrid client side data filtering is searching text from all data (previous and new data) and pagination data is not getting updated. It is pulling previously retrieved data. Please find  following code:

```
  <html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8"/>
     <title>BackGrid complete example</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="backgrid-0.3.5.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="backgrid-select-all.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="backgrid-paginator.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="backgrid-filter.css">
    </head>
    <body>
         <h1>BackGrid complete example with filters and paginator</h1>
         <div id="example-2-result" class="backgrid-container"></div>
         <button id="recButton">Get Records</button>
         <button id="secButton">Set Records</button>
         <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
         <script src="underscore-1.6.0.js"></script>
         <script src="backbone-1.1.2.js"></script>
         <script src="backbone-pageable.js"></script>
         <script src="backgrid-0.3.5.js"></script>
         <script src="backgrid-select-all.js"></script>
         <script src="backgrid-paginator.js"></script>
         <script src="backgrid-filter.js"></script>
         <style>
         .backgrid-container {
            border: 0 none;
            display: block;
            height: 230px;
            overflow: auto;
            padding: 0;
            position: relative;
            width: 20%;
         } 
        </style>
        <script>
             $(function() {
                //Json data
                var data = [{"id":1,"name":"Abandon"},{"id":2,"name":"Abandoned"}];

                var data1 = [{"id":41936,"name":"Hoffman 4"}];

                var columns = [{
                    name: "id", // The key of the model attribute
                    label: "ID", // The name to display in the header
                    renderable: false, // By default every cell in a column is editable, but *ID* shouldn't be
                    // Defines a cell type, and ID is displayed as an integer without the ',' separating 1000s.
                    cell: "integer"
                  }, {
                    name: "name",
                    label: "Name",
                    editable: false,
                    // The cell type can be a reference of a Backgrid.Cell subclass, any Backgrid.Cell subclass instances like *id* above, or a string
                    cell: "string" // This is converted to "StringCell" and a corresponding class in the Backgrid package namespace is looked up
                }];

                var PageableTerritories = Backbone.PageableCollection.extend({
                  url: "justToMakeGridHappy",
                   state: {
                    pageSize: 1
                  },
                  mode: "client" // page entirely on the client side
                });

                //Created pageable dataset
                var pageableTerritories = new PageableTerritories(data);

                // Set up a grid to use the pageable collection
                var pageableGrid = new Backgrid.Grid({
                  columns: [{
                    // enable the select-all extension
                    name: "",
                    cell: "select-row",
                    headerCell: "select-all"
                  }].concat(columns),
                  collection: pageableTerritories
                });

                // Render the grid
                var $example2 = $("#example-2-result");
                $example2.append(pageableGrid.render().el);

                // Initialize the paginator
                var paginator = new Backgrid.Extension.Paginator({
                  collection: pageableTerritories
                });

                // Render the paginator
                $example2.after(paginator.render().el);

                // Initialize a client-side filter to filter on the client
                // mode pageable collection's cache.
                var filter = new Backgrid.Extension.ClientSideFilter({
                  collection: pageableTerritories,
                  placeholder: "Search",
                  fields: ['name']
                });

                // Render the filter
                $example2.before(filter.render().el);

                // Add some space to the filter and move it to the right
                $(filter.el).css({float: "right", margin: "20px"});

                // Fetch some data
                pageableTerritories.fetch({reset: true});

                //retrieves checkbox selected records
                function getSelectedRecords(){
                    console.log("Selected Records : "+ pageableGrid.getSelectedModels());
                }
                //Get Selected Records button click event
                $("#recButton").click(function (e) {
                    getSelectedRecords();
                });

                //For Setting new data
                function setRecords(){
                    pageableTerritories.set(data1); 
                }

                //Set Records button click event                    
                $("#secButton").click(function (e) {
                    setRecords();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

For first time I am setting data(variable data) to grid using constructor. For this data grid, filter and pagination is working properly. As soon as I set data on "set record" button click I am able to find data appeared on grid, For this data pagination is not getting updated and filter filters a data form both data set. Is their any method through which I can flush out previously loaded data so that filter and pagination will work properly?

Comment: Maybe try adding a  pageableGrid.render(); after your setRecords(); call in the click function?

Comment: I tired to make change as per suggestion Still pagination and filter data set is not getting updated.